# blur the background when click on image?

Tags: html, css

is there is a way to when I click on image another image come bigger then the background blur Gradually?

I have tried the modal, and its make the picture larger than what I want

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can use this plugin : http://photoswipe.com/
and using css try to make the background opacity .9 or less as you want

or use jquery gallery plugin : https://plugins.jquery.com/gallerie/.